# Images display in backend and frontend thumbnails, but nowhere else

Tags: frontend

I've tried every fix I can searching Google, such as permissions, owner, etc and I just cannot get images to display properly again.

This was working fine up until recently and I have no idea what has triggered it...

Here is a few images of the problem:
[image: backend]
[image: frontend]
[image: frontend2]
[image: frontend3]

When I right click the image and open it on the product page, I get the following:

```
skin/frontend/default/default/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg
```

While the thumbnails are showing:

```
media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/56x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/t/e/temple-haze-w_1_.jpg
```

And the backend is showing:

```
media/catalog/product/t/e/temple-haze-w_1_.jpg
```

Comment: Did you try setting you permission to 777 recessively on media/catalog/product to make sure it not a permission issue (then reset after)

Comment: I did a recursive chmod of 777 inside the Media folder, yes.

Comment: Did you can check in template file catalog/product/list.phtml.

Comment: I've checked it and it appears to be normal, nothing that I can notice out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

Stupid me forgot to turn off Developer mode inside nginx config, I commented out:

```
fastcgi_param   MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE true;
```